# Select random images using Linq/C#?

Tags: c#, linq, file, random

I am trying to select existing images from a directory.  The image files are being renamed dynamically when they are created  but the format they currently have cannot be changed.  This is an example.

client_2010_10_23_001.jpg

Essentially, the images are names according to upload time and incremented.  Perhaps split the file name into an array and select that way?  I think that could be the right direction but I'm having trouble conceiving the approach.

Thanks!

Comment: You go into great length about the name of the image files. Since grabbing a random image from a file dir has nothing to do with the file name is there a reason you bring this up?

Comment: I was just trying to avoid answers that included the old stand by of randomly selecting images like 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc.  The image names had to be unchanged and because I couldn't conceive a solution it was difficult to know what "not" to include if you follow my meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
var allImages = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*.jpg");
var random = new Random();
var randomImage = allImages[random.Next(allImages.Length)];
```